# How to disable bootstrap default behaviour on bootstrap collapse plugin

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

So what I am looking at is:

- When you click the header of the collapsable object, then nothing should happen
- While `$("#collapseOne").collapse('toggle');` or `$("#collapseTwo").collapse('toggle');` should succeed

The Collabsable object:

```
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
      <div class="accordion-group mzti-transparent-border" id="id-group-1">
        <div id="id-header-1" class="accordion-heading mzti-bg-image-1">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">

            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">

          <div class="accordion-inner">


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-group hide mzti-transparent-border mzti-height" id="id-group-2">
        <div id="id-header-2" class="accordion-heading width-100 mzti-bg-image-2 margin-top-22px ">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">

          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
          <div class="accordion-inner">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `data-toggle="collapse"` on the `<a class="accordion-toggle"...` elements

Comment: this is not working in nested accordion. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for hours! Just for clarification, this IS the solution if you are trying to use javascript to expand and collapse your elements. Thank you very much!